# how to calculate distance between two points in Java

Tags: java, distance

Hi I am really new to Java. I really don't have an idea on what I can do to make this code work at all.

```
public class Distance
{   private int xOne,yOne,xTwo,yTwo;
    private double distance;
    public Distance()
    {

    }

    public Distance(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
    {       x1=xOne;
            x2=xTwo;
            y1=yOne;
            y2=yTwo;
    }

    public void setCoordinates(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
    {
        xOne=4;
        yOne=3;
        xTwo=6;
        yTwo=56;    
    }

    public void calcDistance()
    {
        Math.sqrt((xTwo-xOne)*(xTwo-xOne)+(yTwo-yOne)*(yTwo-yOne));
    }

    public void print( )
    {
        out.println("x1:");
        out.println("y1:");
        out.println("x2:");
        out.println("y2:");
        out.println(distance);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try making your code a little more professional. We would be happy to help, just phrase your question in a more appropriate way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entire `Distance` class could be reduced to a single method. But I guess this is a learning exercise so I'll try and help you step-by-step with everything I can:

- All of your `int` variables for the points would be more useful if they were `double`s. Then you can use fractional positions and a greater range of distances.
- These variables: `private int xOne,yOne,xTwo,yTwo;` would be better named `x1, y1, x2, y2`.
- Your `setCoordinates` method is currently ignoring the arguments and assigning hard-coded values, for testing I suppose. Anyway, assuming you fix that and you change the field names as I suggested, you'll need to distinguish between the local variable and the field of the same name, which you can do by qualifying access to the field with the prefix `this.`, so you get:

  ```
  public void setCoordinates(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
      this.x1 = x1;
      this.y1 = y1;
      this.x2 = x2;
      this.y2 = y2;
  }
  ```
- This constructor isn't doing anything since the assignments are backwards:

  ```
  public Distance(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
  {       x1=xOne;
          x2=xTwo;
          y1=yOne;
          y2=yTwo;
  }
  ```

  Should be:

  ```
          xOne=x1;
  ```

  and so on.

  However, you already have a `setCoordinates` method to do the same thing, so it makes sense to call that instead of repeating yourself:

  ```
  public Distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
      setCoordinates(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  }
  ```
- The `calcDistance` method doesn't currently work because after calculating the answer, it doesn't assign it to the `distance` variable, or do anything else with it. The assignment should be:

  ```
  public void calcDistance() {
      distance = Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
  }
  ```
- A dedicated function, [`Math.hypot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#hypot-double-double-) exists, which calculates `√(x² + y²)`. Using that simplifies things:

  ```
  public void calcDistance() {
      distance = Math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
  }
  ```
- Next, consider when you would actually call the `calcDistance` method... It would always be after setting the coordinates, right? So why not subsume the math into `setCoordinates`, and remove the `calcDistance` method entirely, to simplify use of the class:

  ```
  public void setCoordinates(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
      this.x1 = x1;
      this.y1 = y1;
      this.x2 = x2;
      this.y2 = y2;
      this.distance = Math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
  }
  ```
- Examining your `print` method, the statements to print the coordinates don't actually do so:

  ```
  out.println("x1:");
  ```

  should be:

  ```
  out.println("x1:" + x1);
  ```
- Using `out.println(...);` is legal, assuming that at the top of the file you've a  declaration `import static java.lang.System.out;`, but it is non-standard. Consider changing that to `System.out.println(...);`.
- Finally, reconsider the entire `Distance` class. It's supposed to calculate distances between points but most of the methods are devoted to getting the coordinates into it and getting the result out of it. You've provided two different ways of getting the coordinates into it: either using the the no-args constructor followed by `setCoordinates`, or using the 4-args constructor.

  You've provided one way of getting the result out, the `print` method, but it's usefulness is limited. It's not very *general* because it allows output only to the console (useless in a GUI app) and only in a fixed format. You could add a `getDistance` method (or make the `distance` field `public`) to increase its usefulness, but let's see what that would look like.

  Imagine that typical use of the class always looks like this:

  ```
  /* ... get x1,y1,x2,y2 ... */
  Distance distance = new Distance();
  distance.setCoordinates(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  double result = distance.getDistance();
  /* ... do something with the result ... */
  ```

  It turns out that `Distance` is just a glorified function. So let's turn it into a real function that returns the result directly:

  ```
  static double calcDistance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
      return Math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
  }
  ```

  (It's `static` because it no longer requires an instance of a class to be created.) This method is now so small and portable it could be placed in any class, and doesn't need the dedicated `Distance` class. You could place it in a class called `MathUtils`, for example, along with other useful bits and pieces. Anyway, using it is now simpler:

  ```
  /* ... get x1,y1,x2,y2 ... */
  double distance = MathUtils.calcDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  /* ... do something with the result ... */
  ```

  What about printing the output? Well, printing, in that particular format, was not part of the *general* usefulness of the function. If you only need to do it once, that's something that can be done in the caller. If you need to calc and print distances in that format from several places in the code, that's a candidate for a method, but not the same method, because it's better to keep `calcDistance` itself general. Something like this would do:

  ```
  static void printDistance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
      System.out.println("x1:" + x1);
      System.out.println("y1:" + y1);
      System.out.println("x2:" + x2);
      System.out.println("y2:" + y2);
      System.out.println("distance:" + calcDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2));
  }
  ```

Anyway, I hope this solves your problem. Feel free to use any/all parts of this answer, as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the distance variable with the result

```
distance = Math.sqrt((xTwo-xOne)*(xTwo-xOne)+(yTwo-yOne)*(yTwo-yOne));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change `Math.sqrt((xTwo-xOne)*(xTwo-xOne)+(yTwo-yOne)*(yTwo-yOne));` with `distance = Math.sqrt( (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 );`.
And,

```
out.println("x1:");
out.println("y1:");
out.println("x2:");
out.println("y2:");
out.println(distance);
```

with

```
System.out.println("x1 : " + x1);
System.out.println("y1 : " + y1);
System.out.println("x2 : " + x2);
System.out.println("y2 : " + y2);
System.out.println("distance : " + distance);
```

You may refer [this website](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/) to learn java basics.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong, to be honest.

1. You  are not assigning the global variables to the local ones properly in `Distance` constructor.
2. Your `setCoordinates` method is useless since you are not using the parameters at all.
3. You are not assigning `Math.sqrt()` to a value
4. You need to put `System.out.println()` rather than just `println()`